Problema con array list en Java
estoy haciendo un ejercicio de Java, su enunciado es el siguiente: Implementar una aplicación que pida por consola números enteros no negativos hasta que se introduce -1. Los números se iráninsertando en una colección, pudiéndose repetir. Al terminar, se mostrará la colección por pantalla. A continuación, se mostrarántodos los valores pares. Por último, se eliminarán todos los múltiplos de 3 y se mostrará por pantalla la colección resultante.
Estoy teniendo problemas con la parte de que se añadan los números en el array list y no sé dónde está el fallo. Soy estudiante así que si es un fallo ridículo ya saben por qué es.
Aquí les dejo el código:
package ejercicio1.src.main.java.ejercicio1;
import java.util.ArrayList; //importar array list
import java.util.Scanner; //importar scanner

/*Implementar una aplicación que pida por consola números enteros no negativos hasta
que se introduce -1. Los números se irán
insertando en una colección, pudiéndose repetir. Al terminar, se mostrará la colección
por   pantalla. A continuación, se mostrarán
todos los valores pares. Por último, se eliminarán todos los múltiplos de 3 y se
mostrará por pantalla la colección resultante.
*/

class Numeros{

//atributo(s)
private static ArrayList<Integer> numeros;

//constructor
public Numeros() {
    numeros = new ArrayList<>();
}


    /**
 * método para mostrar la colección
 */
public static void mostrarTodo(ArrayList<Integer> numeros){
    for (Integer numero : numeros) {
        System.out.println(numero);
    }
}

/**
 * método para mostrar solamente los números pares
 */
public static void mostrarPares(ArrayList<Integer> numeros){
    for (Integer numero : numeros) {
        if (numero % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println(numero);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * método para eliminar los múltiplos de 3
 */
public static void eliminarMultiplosTres(ArrayList<Integer> numeros){
    numeros.removeIf(numero -> numero % 3 == 0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //activar scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Numeros<Integer> numeros = new Numeros<>();
    Numeros numeros = new Numeros();

    //bucle principal
    int numero;
    do {
        System.out.print("Por favor, introduce un número entero y positivo: ");
        numero = sc.nextInt(); //pedir el número
        if (numero >= 0) {
            numeros.add(numero); //si el número cumple los requisitos se añade al array list
        } else{
            System.err.print("Has introducido un número negativo, por favor introduce un número positivo.");
        } //si el número no cumple los requisitos se muestra un mensaje de error
    } while (numero != -1); //pedir números mientras el valor introducido no sea -1

    //mostrar los datos
    
    //mostrar la colección completa
    System.out.println("Todos los números:");
    mostrarTodo();

    //mostrar solo los números pares
    System.out.println("Números pares:");
    mostrarPares();

    //eliminar múltiplos de 3
    System.out.println("Eliminando múltiplos de 3...");
    eliminarMultiplosTres();

    //mostrar la colección final
    System.out.println("Colección final:");
    mostrarTodo();
}

}


Si estas haciendo uso de una clase con métodos propios ,evita usar el "static" , esto hace que invoques los métodos de manera directa haciendo que tu constructor no sea requerido ( y si esta ahí es por algo )

Tus métodos tal y como están declarados reciben un parámetro , en este caso una lista , la cual estas evitando .

Si el ArrayList nace en el constructor de la clase accede a ella mediante el objeto creado asignándole a una nueva lista creada en tu método "main".

Nombra tus variables de manera distinta si tu Arraylist es "numeros" el objeto de la clase Numeros no puede llamarse igual ;)
private  ArrayList numeros;
  public Numeros() {
      numeros = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public  void mostrarTodo(ArrayList<Integer> numeros){
      for (Integer numero : numeros) {
          System.out.println(numero);
      }
  }
  public void mostrarPares(ArrayList<Integer> numeros){
      for (Integer numero : numeros) {
          if (numero % 2 == 0) {
              System.out.println(numero);
          }
      }
  }

  public void eliminarMultiplosTres(ArrayList<Integer> numeros){
      numeros.removeIf(numero -> numero % 3 == 0);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      Numeros numerosClass = new Numeros();

      ArrayList<Integer> lista = numerosClass.numeros;

      int numero;
      do {
          System.out.print("Por favor, introduce un número entero y positivo: ");
          numero = sc.nextInt(); 
          if (numero >= 0) {
              lista.add(numero); 
          } else{
              System.err.print("Has introducido un número negativo, por favor introduce un número positivo.");
          } 
      } while (numero != -1); 

      System.out.println("Todos los números:");
      numerosClass.mostrarTodo(lista);

      System.out.println("Números pares:");
      numerosClass.mostrarPares(lista);

      System.out.println("Eliminando múltiplos de 3...");
      numerosClass.eliminarMultiplosTres(lista);

      System.out.println("Colección final:");
      numerosClass.mostrarTodo(lista);




¡Muchísimas gracias!
